# string match function

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, .net-4.0

Hi
  I like to build a string function:

```
if member of a list of string: 
    "Nissan" from "Honda, Toyota, Nissan, Mazda"

  if start with or end with
    "Nissan" from "Nis*" as start with 
    "Nissan" from "*san" as end with

  if not start with or end with 
    "Ford" from "^Nis*" as start with 
    "Ford" from "^*san" as end with 

  if Not member of a list of string:
    "Ford" from "^Hon*, ^Toy*, Nis*, Mazda"
```

I was thinking Regex maybe the solution, but how I implement it?

Thank you
Wes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to understand what you are asking for, but I will do my best to guess:

1. To check if string is one of the following: `Honda, Toyota, Nissan, Mazda`

   `^(Honda|Toyota|Nissan|Mazda)$`
2. Starts with `Nis`

   ```
   ^Nis.*$
   ```
3. Ends with `san`

   ```
   ^.*san$
   ```
4. Not starts with `Nis`

   ```
   ^(?!Nis).*
   ```
5. Not ends with `san`

   ```
   ^.*(?<!san)$
   ```
6. Does not contain any of `Hon*, Toy*, Nis*, Mazda`

   ```
   ^(?!Hon.*|Toy.*|Nis.*|Mazda).*
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are asking but

if you have

```
List<string> strings = ...
```

and

```
string input = ...
```

then you can do

```
bool memberIsInList = strings.Contains(input);      
bool memberStartsOrEndsWith = strins.Any(s => s.StartsWith(input) || s.EndsWith(input));
```

for the other two should be similar, mixing in the not operator (`!`)